# Flask-SQLAlchemy won't connect to remote server

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm trying to use the Flask-SQLAlchemy and Flask-Migrate libraries to connect to a MySQL server, but the app keeps trying to connect to localhost instead of the remote server no matter what I put in the `DATABASE_URI` variable.

Here is my config:

```
import os

class Config(object):
    FLASK_ENV = os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') or 'Development'
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'mysql+pymysql://user:pass@192.168.xxx.xxx/devdb'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

And here is the error when I try to migrate:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I've tested the connection string outside of the Flask app with vanilla SQLAlchemy and it works and I can create tables and add data, etc with the user.

Comment: Are you sure that your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is not pointing to localhost?

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov, the env variable is null since it is in the dev environment.

Comment: Post the part of code where you instantiate your db and import config

Comment: The db is an existing db on the mysql server, but the schema is empty (no tables, etc.)  There is no code that creates it.  The config from my flask app is what is posted above.

Comment: I figured it out.  Even though the environment variable had not been instantiated python reads it as an empty string and not NULL and therefore was not activating the "or."